# Most simple way (URL?) to trigger SOLR commit of all pending docs?

Tags: solr

What's the most simple way to cause a SOLR installation to commit all pending docs?

(There's no obvious way in the admin interface. There's a script called 'commit' mentioned on the page http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrOperationsTools -- but no hint where that lives. 'Commit' is clearly an option that can be added to any update POST, but I can't find any reference to a single URL that serves to only commit.)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**THIS HOLDS FOR SOLR VERSIONS < 5.0**

Try `[solr url]/update?commit=true`

For example, with an URL like the SOLR example defaults, from the same machine, `http://localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true` should do it.

**FOR SOLR VERSIONS >= 5.0**
http://localhost:8983/solr/[collection_name]/update?commit=true

Comment: Would that commit only that update statement or all pending ones?

Comment: It is a stand alone request. Commits everything pending. Just test it.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be something that simple!

Comment: Just clarifying, it is impossible to commit only a subset of pending updates. When you issue a commit to Solr, it will write all 'adds' and 'deletes' always.

Comment: This is not working anymore starting from SOLR 5.X, the collection name is required.

http://localhost:8080/solr/collection_name/update?commit=true

Answer (score 37):

Since Solr 5 it is required to add collection name into the url, so  now the right answer is:

http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name/update?commit=true

In the previous versions it was possible to have a default collection (it was usually collection1, from the examples) and the shortened version was valid:

http://localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true

Still, it was possible to name the collection like in the first case.

Answer (score 8):

I would say there is something missing in "right" answer - URL should contain collection name like: http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/update?commit=true

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but just to say that there is also a way to do this via the admin interface.

Simply click:

-> dataimport on the left menu

-> then tick the commit checkbox

-> then execute

You will see a message like:
"Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 1 documents. Deleted 0 documents. (Duration: 01s)"