# Paginating through Solr search results

Tags: solr, pagination

I am trying to paginate through the results of a very broad query but Solr returns only 10 results even when the rows and start parameters are present.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/patents/query?q=*:*&rows=10000000&start=9
```

This returns:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "start":"9",
      "rows":"10000000"}},
  "response":{"numFound":10,"start":9,"docs":[
      {
        "date":"1980-07-10T00:00:00Z",
        "id":117008,
        "country":"US",
        "title":"Solr test",
        "_version_":1525967658488430592}]
  }}
```

What is the best way to paginate through several thousand documents?

Comment: What is the goal of this? Anyway fetching bulks of documents from Solr via such a high rows value is not a good idea. Paging implies fetching small batches. If you want to route/transfer docs from your index somewhere else, there are better approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deep paging you should be using cursors as performance deteriorates with high values of `start` in standard requests: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results

Your current query looks technically sound (albeit bad from a performance viewpoint) and your index simply has only 10 documents as stated by `numFound`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems while the data import is running Solr sees only 10 documents probably because of the previous debug run.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Frequent commits are normally quite costly with Solr, so for batch indexing it makes sense to do them rarely or only once (at the end). If you wish to see the progress of your job, you can issue a manual commit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815628/most-simple-way-url-to-trigger-solr-commit-of-all-pending-docs

Comment: Perform a softCommit ( `<commit softCommit='true' />` ) if you want to track progress. That is way cheaper and faster.