# Solr not showing updated documents

Tags: curl, solr

I'm trying to update a specific field in a solr document. For testing purposes I'm using the author field. Afterwards i will try to update the date field. I'm using curl in cygwin terminal. This is the command I'm entering in the terminal:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/MaharaPortfolioA/update -d '[{"url":"https://www.moopaed.de/mahara/view/view.php?id=6920","author":{"set":"Herbert"}}]'
```

To check for a success I'm using the following command and getting this response:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/MaharaPortfolioA/get?id="https://www.moopaed.de/mahara/view/view.php?id=6920"
{
  "doc":
  {
    "url":"https://www.moopaed.de/mahara/view/view.php?id=6920",
    "portfolio_title":"IT 2 Portfolio - View 2",
    "title":"Themenschwerpunkt Informationssysteme  - moopaed mahara",
    "author":"Herbert",
    "indexDate":"2017-04-05T22:04:10Z",
    "nrImages":8,
    "nrWords":7474,
    "nrUploadedImages":6,
    "nrLinks":0,
    "cohort":"IT3 WS 2013/2014",
    "lecture":"OOP",
    "nrWikipediaImages":0,
    "nrWikipediaLinks":0,
    "_version_":1564023239370342400}}
```

According the response everything seems fine: The vaule of author changed from "Louisa" to "Herbert". But if I'm using a query the search for "Herbert" I get no result (http://localhost:8983/solr/MaharaPortfolioA/select?q=Herbert). On my search for a solution I found different possible reasons for that problem:

- The specific field must be set stored="true". It is set true for author.
- After my update I optimized the core via "optimize" button in solr admin panel.
- I did a commit with: http://localhost:8983/solr/MaharaPortfolioA/update?commit=true . I used this solution: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815628/most-simple-way-url-to-trigger-solr-commit-of-all-pending-docs)

I have no further ideas why my search for "Herbert" gives me no response.

- Is it because my unique key is a url and not an integer value?
- Or is it because I'm using Curl via Cygwin? Furthermore there's a
  difference between cURL (Client for URLs) and curl (programming
  language). If tutorials use this term, do they refer to cURL?
- Another reason could be that "author" gets filtered and tokenized while indexing. Maybe my update doesn't run through these actions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do logs say?

Comment: @Oyeme As i tried to change "nrWords" the log was: 
'2017-04-07 14:02:28.745 INFO  (qtp870698190-14) [   x:MaharaPortfolioA] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [MaharaPortfolioA]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={}{add=[https://www.moopaed.de/mahara/view/view.php?id=6093 (1564028435152502784)]} 0 15'

Comment: Have you tried to add commit=true into your link ? curl curl http://localhost:8983/solr/MaharaPortfolioA/update?commit=true -d '[{"url":"https://www.moopaed.de/mahara/view/view.php?id=6920","author":{"set":"Herbert"}}]' ( finally the commit=true parameter tells Solr to commit the update we are sending to it on this request.)

Comment: I added commit=true to my link but the problem stays the same. The strange thing is that "Herbert" appears in the author facet while he is not searchable. In contrast "Louisa" and all other original authors are searchable.

Comment: try to restart solr service, sometimes indexes could be messed up...

Comment: I did this several times. Is it possible that my solr-server isnt acting correctly? I mean i got my configuration files from an university project and already corrected some mistakes in schema.xml. So it's possible that there are more mistakes which I'cant find since I'm a solr newbie. Does the solrconfig.xml contain update-relevant code?

Comment: Could be, it's hard to say without seeing solrconfig.xml. Try to download and compare your solrconfig with default one. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig

Comment: Are you _actually_ searching the `author` field? `q=author:Herbert` would be the standard Lucene syntax for querying `author`. When you're using `q=Herbert`, the search goes to the default search field, which probably isn't `author`.

Comment: @MatsLindh Ouch! You are right! I always thought, that I searched all fields. But it seems that I only search the text field. So my primary problem is solved. Thank you MatsLindh and Oyeme. But another problem appears: as soon as I change a field, the value of 'text' disappears. It already isn't listed above in my curl response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually searching the author field: `q=author:Herbert` would be the standard Lucene syntax for querying for author. When you're using `q=Herbert`, the search goes to the default search field, which probably isn't author (but usually `text`).

If you're using the `edismax` or `dismax` query parsers, you can use `qf=author text` to search both the `text` and the `author` field, and you can use `qf=author^5 text` to give more relevancy weight to hits in the `author` field.

The default configuration of the `text` field is probably not as `stored="true"`, which will discard the actual content (and only keep the indexed terms for searching).

If you're indexing content using the [ExtractingRequestHandler / Apache Tika  / Solr Cell](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika), the content is added in a field called `content`. If that field doesn't exist, the content is dropped.

> Tika adds all the extracted text to the content field.

You can use `fmap.content=<fieldname>` to map the content to a different field name.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all make sure the field 'author' is set to indexed="true" in the schema and set with the type you are expecting. You can play with it with the analysis tool of the Solr admin and the schema browser to validate your assumptions.
2. You used the realtime get to assess the update worked well. Which is fine, but bare in mind the realtime get works even if no commit happened ( as it works in cooperation with the Transaction Log), so be sure a softcommit or an hard commit ( with openSearcher=true is triggered)
3. be sure your query make sense to your use case. If you want to search specifically by the author "author:Herbert" is the correct query.